# UPDATE IF EXISTS error

Tags: mysql, sql

Im try to update value (level) in in table people if userid exist in users table
in table

```
  IF EXISTS (SELECT userid FROM users)
  UPDATE people SET level='1'
```

What i am missing ! to get errors ?

Comment: `users` and `people` have any common column to join?

Comment: Your syntax seems correct. What are the tables ?

Comment: userid is common column , but i need to update level column if userid exist in both table with value 1

Comment: @dystroy  tables are users and people

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your comment *"i need to update level column if userid exist in both table with value 1"*, it seems you need this :

```
UPDATE
    `people`
SET
    `level` = 1
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            `users`
        WHERE
            users.userid = people.userid
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do select. All you need is:

```
UPDATE people SET level='1' WHERE userid IS NOT NULL
```

BTW, what db are you running?

**UPD.** Sorry, I missed the fact that you have two tables. I can recomend to do something like the following:

```
UPDATE people SET level='1' WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
users.userid = people.userid)
```

Also, `UPDATE` can be done with `JOIN`, but that depends on what db are you using.

Comment: Those seem to be two different tables : users and people.

Comment: @Eugeny89 I user mysql , and yes its different tables i cant use this to update !

Answer (score 2):

With MySQL, "EXISTS" clause on "UPDATE" simply don't work.

Use instead a JOIN condiction:

```
UPDATE people A, (SELECT userid FROM users) B SET A.level='1'
```

However, I suppose you should use some WHERE clause also... ;)

For example, this one update "level" on "people" table, only if exists a join value on "users" table...

```
UPDATE people A, users B SET A.level='1' WHERE A.userid=B.userid;
```