# MYSQL - How can I update my record occurency count (1,2,3,4,..) in the same table for existing data with wrong occurency counts

Tags: mysql, database

[image][image]I have a table with a count column, each time am adding a new record I update the count column with 1 if no similar count exists else I increment by 1, this is working well for me, my challenge is currently my records have the wrong counts for example have many with 3 yet they are the first occurrences in their group (I got this mix up when I instead of deleting higher duplicate I delete the lower). can't do it manually as records are about 20K

```
***my table fields***

id, householdID, date, score, visitCount.

Each time a household is visit I update the visit count when inserting the record based on the number of similar records for the same household.
```

***How can I update my record to have the right visitCount: 1 for the first occurrence, 2 for the second, and so one for each household*?**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/692160/1)

Comment: Please provide a sqlfiddle with minimal reproducible example for your table schema, data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UPDATE IF EXISTS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436122/update-if-exists-error)

Comment: no it does not , I want to update my records to have the right counts: 1,2,3,4 a record may exist but it should be updated with the right occurrence count, if its the first occurrence 1 if its the second 2 and so on

Comment: You want to count the records (aggregate) and then update the records?

Comment: Have realised what you suggested gives a hint though it not conclusive, I have a scenario where the visit count is 3 but its the only record for that I want to correct so to 1, then a scenario where visit count is 3 yet there are 2 records only I want to find the first one update it to 1 then the one with 3 to be corrected to 2 and so on

Comment: Yes after you commented with your logic, it helped for someone to post the answer for you. Next time, include your logic in the question clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the logic you are looking for is:

```
SELECT id, 
  hhid, 
  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY hhid ORDER BY id) as visitCount,
  hh_score
FROM yourtable;
```

This will give you the right answer for each `id`/`hhid` combination that you can use to perform your update to correct your table.

I would question why you want to store this number when it's so easily derived from your data. Short of a performance bump if this selected often, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Thank this helps me solve my problem, grateful

Comment: On the reason why we store the number is we have about 20K rows are they are increasing and we need to know the visit count in a couple of features of the application on the front end. Each time we get the record we want to know its instance number for the reports we want to display not storing it would require querying entire db to determine the instance number, but we are going to explore your advice

Comment: Totally makes sense. Materializing the count in that case makes perfect sense so you aren't relying on compute to spit out answers. Ultimately it's the cost of calculating upfront (x frequency) compared to the cost of calculating on the fly (x frequency) AND the need to retrieve the data quickly for UI.

Comment: For sure and in the future for derived variables not frequently used will rely on generating them as when needed instead of storing them.   - Also at the time I didn't know of the row_number() function could you have a reference where I can refresh and advance my SQL querying knowledge

Comment: You bet. That is a type of function called a "Window Function". Mysql documentation has a good write up: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html This functionality exists in most other RDBMS's as well so it's a good one to learn.

Comment: Thank am going to make use of the documentation to get up to speed